# How can I select only the outer element (table / list)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'd like to apply a style only to an outer element (a table), not for the nested on.

Due to the complexity of the system (and since I don't know for sure which other formats are used for the inner tables) I don't want to change the style for all elements first and then overwrite them for the nested ones (that's easy) but really only address the outer elements / tables (also I can't apply classes for now, because them I have to fix that I a bunch of code).

So I have something like that:

```
<body>
   <div>
    <...>
     <table>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <table>
                     <tr>
                         <td>
                          I'm some content!
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
             </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
    <...>
   </div>
</body>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/MichaelBootstrap/pen/bGBEbYy

First try was

```
body *:not(table) table:not(.no_tab_margin) { 
    border: thin solid green; /* just to visualise it */
}
```

(I use the class `.no_tab_margin` to stop that ugly fix on all pages, where I change the layout to responsive)
But due to the right-to-left resolution of the browsers, this is still applied to all tables.

How do I have to change the CSS selector such that it only applies on outer tables?

To prevent typical answers: Yes, that would do, but overwrite/reset other styling from the inner tables:

```
table:not(.no_tab_margin) { 
    border: thin solid green; 
}
table table:not(.no_tab_margin) { 
    border: unset; /* all borders from all inner tables are gone */
}
```

If I didn't find a solution with CSS I will write a small jQuery script (Apply a class on all outer tables), that will do that.

To stop discussions about nested tables: Yes, that's long outdated. But I can't change it right now. The system contains more than 500 form/pages, which are generated by PHP. And, yes - I will remove them step by step (and make it all responsive), but that's my job for the next2-3 years - no joke).

Same is also relevant for nested lists (`<ul><li><ul> ...`) so that not only a special question only for old systems.

Comment: if you only want top level tables, I would wrap them in a div with a class and then target it with the direct child combinator, although you are probably better of just adding a class to the top level table and using that

Comment: Or add a class to the first table and just use that class selector.

Comment: Can you show the code you have hidden behind the ellipsis that shows up before the outer table starts?

Comment: Too complicated for something that can be easily solved with a class

Comment: what about `table:not(table table) {}` https://jsfiddle.net/y3k6b7x9/

Comment: @TylerH: the code in <...>  vaiates  in more than 500 varaiants (>500 diffent pages)! But Pete already solves it  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from pete solves it perfectly:

```
table:not(table table) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Class or an ID.
And define the custom styles

Comment: As describe above, that do not work because I'm really have to handle more than 1000 totally different tables, which are spreaded  in PHP-code over more than 50.000 line of code. (I will do that step by step over the next years)